# System Volume Information folder huge

Tags: windows, windows-10, disk-space

I have yet another problem with the System Volume Information folder on my machine. I'm using Windows 10 Home 21H2. The folder occupies ~150GB (that is **~60%** of my C: drive)

Among other sources, I used information from [here](http://woshub.com/how-to-clean-up-system-volume-information-folder/)

I tried:

- Cleaning using CleanMgr.exe (normal & admin)
- Reducing space for Sytem Restore points (to 10%)
- Deleting all System Restores (there were none)
- Disabling System Restore
- Checked Volume Shadow Copy

  - `vssadmin list shadows` reports no shadows exist
  - `vssadmin list shadowstorage` reports 0MB used for shadows, max 1% storage for shadows
- Checked Windows Backups

  - `wbadmin get versions` reports no backups
- Tried DiskShadow tool, does not exist (only for Windows Server?)

Nothing helped, size only reduced minimally

I used the FolderSize tool to analyze the storage, and found out that the largest part is occupied by single files with GUIDs as names (there are >100 of them, dating back to the year 2018):

[image: File sizes in FolderSize]

I understand the importance of the System Volume Information folder and you should not mess with it. But from the link above, the relevant data like backups, quotas, deduplication, etc. is stored not in those files. They seem to be Disk Snapshots.

**My question**: Is it safe to delete those files?

**Update from comments**:
Output of `vssadmin list shadowstorage`:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>vssadmin list shadowstorage
vssadmin 1.1 - Volume Shadow Copy Service administrative command-line tool
(C) Copyright 2001-2013 Microsoft Corp.

No items found that satisfy the query.
```

**Update 2:**
I checked using a hexeditor, and then a self-made program. ALL files only contain 0-Bytes (many of them of several GBs).

**Udate 3:**
I followed @harrymc advice and moved the files to another folder (using Linux Live USB) and observed the system for several days, if the system runs correctly and if new files appear.

In this time, I used the laptop as usual, hibernated , restarted, shut down, and had a Windows Update installed. I experienced no issues

The files did not reappear.

Also, system checks as pointed out by others (dism, chkdsk, sfc) did not report any issues

I made some statistics, and found out that at the beginning, the files were created back-to-back, so the creation date of a file was the same as the last-written date of a previous file. Then some gaps started to show up (regions where no file existed), of 1-3 days, and recently there were gaps of 1-2 months.

The last file was from 6.10.2022, I moved the files on 12.10.2022 (so ~1 week later).

Comment: From admin CMD Prompt, you could copy one of those files to your desktop, and try to open it using 7-Zip. If you can't access the SVI folder, then try launching CMD.exe [as System](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/run-program-as-system-localsystem-account-windows/)

Comment: Could you include the output of `vssadmin list shadowstorage`?

Comment: Try: In an elevated PowerShell, run `Start-DedupJob -Type GarbageCollection -Priority High -Volume "C:"`.

Comment: @harrymc I don't have the `Start-DedupJob` Cmdlet. From what I gather from the resources, deduplication applies only to windows server, but I have Windows 10 home. And as there is no Start-DedupJob, I don't think this is about deduplication garbage...

Comment: @w32sh I managed to open such a file (~4GB) in a hex editor. It was all NULL-Bytes... This looks like pure garbage

Comment: If they are garbage, you could move them all elsewhere, then delete if no problem arises for a few days. Watch to see if they return. If this is hard to do in Windows, use a Linux Live USB.

Comment: I'm sure you don't want to hear this, but Windows may be corrupt (based on those garbage files & the quantity of them) & it might be a good idea to plan a reinstall. In the meantime you can try the normal repairs: `sfc /scannow` & `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth`

Comment: Just in case, you should check the filesystem integrity using `chkdsk`.

Comment: I ran `chkdsk`, `sfc` and `dism`, all reporting a clean system

Comment: +1. Interesting, I have been experiencing the same problem of the C drive free space going to 0. The culprit was the Volume Shadow Copies that you referenced - I was able to delete the shadow volumes and it freed up space. Oddly enough, they were set to UNBOUND growth (i.e., 100%). What is odd is that there are no restore or backup points set on my computer and neither BitDefender nor MalwareBytes flagged any suspicious behavior. The VSSCV process is set to manual start only. Any idea what could enable this without manual intervention?

Comment: I have added a question here: https://superuser.com/questions/1824193/what-cuases-volume-shadow-copy-to-enable-itself-without-user-intervention

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If these files are garbage, full of zeros, you could move them all
elsewhere.
If no problem arises for a few days, they can be deleted.
If this is hard to do in Windows, use a Linux Live USB.

Watch to see if the files return. If they do, you can check whether
this happens at a certain time, for example after boot, and trace
this period using
[Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon),
which can also do boot-time monitoring if required, to find the
process that creates them. I wouldn't be surprised if that
process turns out to belong to Windows.

Comment: I followed this advice and moved the files using a linux live system. I will watch the system for a few days

Comment: I updated my question with findings. The files did not reappear, so no further investigation for now. I'll except your answer as there is nothing todo at the moment #

Comment: This answer is too generic to be very useful. The correct answer is https://superuser.com/a/1784954/235533 below. Asker, please move the green checkmark.

Comment: @foobarbecue: Restore Point files are not all-zero.

Comment: @harrymc, I see. I hadn't read Update 2, sorry.

Answer (score 11):

These are restore points. If you don't think you need to rollback something, you can delete them as follows:

1. Click on the Windows Icon and search for "Advanced" to open the "Advanced System Settings"
2. System protection > Configure...
3. Delete all restore points for this drive

[image]

Comment: You sure, are a legend!

Answer (score 4):

Here's another command, which can clear SVI not reachable by vssadmin:

```
wmic shadowcopy delete /nointeractive
```

More here:

https://notes.ponderworthy.com/disable-sentinelone-to-permit-svi-cleanup

Answer (score 1):

This folder contains Windows restore point, if you enabled system protection, they are stored here. I find this feature is really useful if you try something really stupid like install third party storage controller (Intel rapid...) and end up with can't be uninstalled -- create restore point before install, install them, not satisfy, do system restore, and they're gone.

If you do hope to clean this folder, go to control panel, all control panel items, recovery, configure system restore, select desired drive, configure, delete. This is a safe way to erase big files under System Volume Information. You may also turn off this feature so files no longer generated.

If there are still large file, delete use Linux tool chain, they are no longer linked to your current running system (safe to treat as dead files).

Comment: Agree. In my case on Win10 22H2 in that folder was 3 big files. Then I checked restore points and there was automatically created at the same dates. Have cleared restore points and files from SVI disapeared.